# Automorphism group of a smooth quadric $Q\subset\mathbb{P}^4$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, automorphism-groups, quadrics

Let $Q$ be the smooth quadric threefold in $\mathbb{P}^4_{\mathbb{C}}$ defined by the equation
$x_0x_4+x_1x_3+x_2^2=0$.

Is it true that the automorphism group of $Q$ is $SO(Q;\mathbb{C})$ which is isomorphic to $SO(5;\mathbb{C})$?

How can I prove $Aut(Q)=SO(Q)$? And can you give a concrete isomorphism between $SO(Q)$ and $SO(5)$?

Comment: Yes: The automorphism group of the quadric is $PO(Q)$. The isomorphism $PO(Q) \cong PO(5)$ can be obtained by diagonalising $Q$. The result follows the fact that the natural map $SO(2k+1) \to PO(2k+1)$ is an isomorphism, for any natural number $k$.

Answer (score 5):

I will expand my comment into an answer.

First, any automorphism of $Q$ is induced by an automorphism of the ambient projective space. This is because any automorphism of $Q$ must fix the canonical bundle, which here is $\mathcal{O}_Q(-3)$. In particular any automorphism must fix $\mathcal{O}_Q(1)$, hence is an automorphism of the ambient projective space.

The collection of projective automorphisms which preserve the quadric is exactly $PO(Q)$. The result then follows the fact that $PO(Q) \cong PO(5)$, together with the fact that the natural map $SO(2k+1)\to PO(2k+1)$ is an isomorphism, for any natural number $k$ (see for instance [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_orthogonal_group).)